# What does ut mean in this sentence

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, new-latin, ut

I'm struggling to find the right translation for 'ut' in the sentence below.  For context, it's part of a property transaction in a Manorial Court Roll from circa 1700.

> Willelmus Taylor dedit Domino pro fine sexdecem libras premanibus soluto et sic admissus est inde Tenens **ut** in revertione sed fidelitas sua respectuatur quousque etc

My current translation is:

> William Taylor gave to the lord for a fine sixteen pounds
> paid beforehand and thus was admitted as tenant thereof in reversion
> but his fealty was respited until etc.

However, I'm not sure this adequately accounts for the 'ut', so I wonder if I'm missing a nuance.

Would 'although' (as an alternative to 'even if') be acceptable? Or is there some other ut construction I should be considering? I don't believe it's a temporal clause, or a clause of purpose or result.

(To be admitted to a tenancy in reversion' was to be recognised in advance as the next tenant when the current tenant died or otherwise relinquished the tenancy).

Comment: Might _ut_ have been unnecessary here, so you can omit it entirely in the English translation?

Comment: @BenKovitz It's possible. However, the phrase ut in revertione crops up dozens of times in a set of 17 court rolls so it isn't a one-off scribal mistak.

Comment: *sic ... ut* = "so ... as" seems to be the construction here, i.e., "so admitted as in reversion," though I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean...